# Is it possible to join MySQL rows independently

Tags: mysql

So I have a table with ids that start with a letter to denote which table ID they're related to, i.e. D86 means they're in the `division` table with id 86, and L86 means they're in the `lab` table with id 86.

So I was wondering if it was possible to do something like `col like 'D%' left join div on ...` and use `lab` for the other one.

Comment: Both `JOIN` operations will happen simultaneously, but you can apply an additional `SELECT` on top of your results to remap them if you want.

Comment: You're probably better off doing the two joins independently, then combining the results with `UNION`.

Comment: @Barmar Yep, that's how I just solved it, thanks for the heads up anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I solved it.

```
SELECT * FROM user 

LEFT JOIN general_group 
    ON general_group.id = user.id 
LEFT JOIN `div` 
    ON `div`.id = substr(general_group.where_id,2)

WHERE general_group.where_id LIKE 'D%'

UNION

SELECT * FROM user 

LEFT JOIN general_group 
    ON general_group.id = user.id 
LEFT JOIN `lab` 
    ON `lab`.id = substr(general_group.where_id,2)

WHERE general_group.where_id LIKE 'L%';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
select . . .
from t left join
     division d
     on t.id = concat('D', d.id) left join
     lab l
     on t.id = concat('L', l.id);
```

Comment: @A.Lau . . . This would normally be more efficient, assuming you don't have multiple matches in the two tables.